# "You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash" error in Django

Tags: python, django, rest, post, django-urls

I'm trying to make a REST API in Django by outputting Json. I'm having problems if I make a POST request using curl in terminal. The error I get is:

> You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and
> you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL
> while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to
> 127.0.0.1:8000/add/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

My url.py is:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
import search

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    
    url(r'^query/$', 'search.views.query'),
    url(r'^add/$','search.views.add'),
)
```

And my views are:

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context,loader
import memcache
import json

def query(request):
    data=['a','b']
    
    mc=memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11221'],debug=0)
    mc.set("d",data);

    val=mc.get("d")
    
    return HttpResponse("MEMCACHE: %s<br/>ORIGINAL: %s" % (json.dumps(val),json.dumps(data)) )

def add(request):
    #s=""
    #for data in request.POST:
    #   s="%s,%s" % (s,data)
    s=request.POST['b']
    return HttpResponse("%s" % s)
```

I know its not giving Json but I'm having the problem mentioned above when I make POST request in terminal

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/ -d b=2 >> output.html
```

I'm new to django though.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

First, make sure that you send the request to `http://127.0.0.1/add/` not `http://127.0.0.1/add`.

Secondly, you may also want to exempt the view from csrf processing by adding the `@csrf_exempt` decorator - since you aren't sending the appropriate token from cURL.

Comment: This is for those who might need the import statement `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`

Answer (score 50):

For URL consistency, Django has a setting called `APPEND_SLASH`, that always appends a slash to the end of the URL if it wasn't sent that way to begin with. This ensures that `/my/awesome/url/` is always served from that URL instead of both `/my/awesome/url` *and* `/my/awesome/url/`.

However, Django does this by automatically redirecting the version without the slash at the end to the one with the slash at the end. Redirects don't carry the state of the request with them, so when that happens your POST data is dropped.

All you need to do is ensure that when you send your POST, you send it to the version with the slash at the end.

Comment: in my curl request "curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/ -d b=2 >> output.html" i am requesting it with a slash at the end but its still giving me problem

Comment: My mistake was that I had & instead of ?: /add/&param1=abc

Answer (score 5):

Simply remove trailing slash from your URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name= 'home'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name= 'contact'),
    path('about/', views.about, name= 'about')
]
```

**Change to**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name= 'home'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name= 'contact'),
    path('about', views.about, name= 'about')
]
```

**OR**

Add trailing slash to action in HTML Form

```
 <form method="POST" action="/contact/">
    {% csrf_token %}
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

FOR GET ==>http://127.0.0.1:8000/create?name=wpwqekhqw/

For POST ==> http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/?name=wpwqekhqw/

You should add '/' after create in POST ... request

Answer (score 1):

Make change in action in Html.
It's worked in my case.

```
<form action="{% url 'add' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario can raise the exact error, not related to either csrf or APPEND_SLASH solution, below an example.

```
 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data= request.data
        print(data['x'])
```

If 'x' does not exist in the payload body, the data['x'] will raise an error, this error in my case gave a false message like the above one.
Hopefully, this will help other developers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slash on url.py

Ex:
From:

```
url(r'^customer/json/set_person/$', views.json_set_person, name='fog.apps.views.json.set_person'),
```

To:

```
url(r'^customer/json/set_person$', views.json_set_person, name='fog.apps.views.json.set_person'),
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be served the urls with and without trailing slash by "/?":

in django 3.X:

```
from django.urls import re_path
re_path(r'^query/?$', 'search.views.query'),
re_path(r'^add/?$','search.views.add'),
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case，I forget to add `AjaxAdmin` when I use `simple-ui`.

From:

```py
@admin.register(xxx)
class xxxAdmin(ExportActionMixin, GAdmin):
```

To:

```py
@admin.register(xxx)
class xxxAdmin(ExportActionMixin, GAdmin, AjaxAdmin):
```

Comment: It isn't clear how this answer addresses the question. Have a look at the guidelines for writing a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below when using **Stripe Webhook** on Django:

> RuntimeError: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in
> a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the
> slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to
> localhost:8000/stripe_webhooks/ (note the trailing slash), or set
> APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

Because even though I defined the url with `/` in `urls.py` in the main folder `core` where `settings.py` is as shown below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

from my_app.views import stripe_webhooks

urlpatterns = [
                  # Here ↓
    path("stripe_webhooks/", stripe_webhooks, name="stripe_webhooks")
]
```

Then, I ran the command without `/` below:

```
                                             # Without "/" ↓
./stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/stripe_webhooks
```

So to solve the error, I put `/` as shown below:

```
                                                    # Here ↓
./stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/stripe_webhooks/
```

Or, I removed `/` from the url as shown below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

from my_app.views import stripe_webhooks

urlpatterns = [
                      # ↓ "/" is removed
    path("stripe_webhooks", stripe_webhooks, name="stripe_webhooks")
]
```

Then, I ran the command without `/` below:

```
                                             # Without "/" ↓
./stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/stripe_webhooks
```