# How get in real time POST update with django and instagram api?

Tags: python, django, real-time, instagram, instagram-api

I try to use [python-instagram](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram) for get in real time instagram's media.

I use api.create_subscription with tag. And my callback url is a django web page on a distant web server. 
My python script (I run it on my local computer):

```
api = InstagramAPI(client_id='my_id', client_secret='my_secret')
sub = api.create_subscription(object='tag', object_id='test', aspect='media', callback_url=my_url/insta)
print sub

while 1:
    pass
```

My django view call by the callback url (I run it on distant web server):

```
def getInstagramPicture(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        mode         = request.GET.get("hub.mode")
        challenge    = request.GET.get("hub.challenge")
        verify_token = request.GET.get("hub.verify_token")
        return HttpResponse(challenge)
    if request.method == "POST":
        print "post"
```

I think the subscription works well. Web server terminal logs:

```
[20/Jan/2015 13:30:11] "GET /insta?hub.challenge=1aed90578d1743a3afb865cc2a6b69cc&hub.mode=subscribe HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[20/Jan/2015 13:30:11] "GET /insta/?hub.challenge=1aed90578d1743a3afb865cc2a6b69cc&hub.mode=subscribe HTTP/1.1" 200 32
```

And local terminal log:

```
sub {'meta': {'code': 200}, 'data': {'object': 'tag', 'object_id': 'test', 'aspect': 'media', 'callback_url': 'my_url/insta', 'type': 'subscription', 'id': '15738925'}}
```

But my problem it's when I try to post on Instagram a picture with tag "test" my view it's not call and I have in my web server terminal:

```
[20/Jan/2015 13:31:24] "POST /insta HTTP/1.1" 500 65563
```

Why my view is not call when I post instagram picture?

Comment: Can you help me? I can't respond to verify  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70880408/respond-to-instagram-webhook-in-django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct your callback url to match what is defined in your urlconf.  You currently tell Instagram that your callback url is `<server>/insta` but from the request logs it seems your urlconf is expecting `<server>/insta/` (with a trailing slash)

This works ok for GET requests, as seen below

```
[20/Jan/2015 13:30:11] "GET /insta?hub.challenge=1aed90578d1743a3afb865cc2a6b69cc&hub.mode=subscribe HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[20/Jan/2015 13:30:11] "GET /insta/?hub.challenge=1aed90578d1743a3afb865cc2a6b69cc&hub.mode=subscribe HTTP/1.1" 200 32
```

(note the first line is a 301 redirect)

Django's default `APPEND_SLASH` setting ensures that the request for `/insta` is automatically redirected to the `/insta/` view that you have defined.

However Django can't do that for a POST request... an HTTP redirect is always a GET request so the POST data would be lost.  This is why you see a 500 error in your logs when a POST request is made to the non-existent url `/insta`:

```
[20/Jan/2015 13:31:24] "POST /insta HTTP/1.1" 500 65563
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9739046/202168

Answer (score 0):

The code shown does not appear to handle POST requests at all. It merely prints out "post" and returns nothing.

The web server log shows a HTTP 500 error (Internal Server Error) and a 64KiB error page that probably tells you exactly why.

You need to implement a handler for POST requests, and this handler would probably be similar to the GET handler that you already have.

Comment: I tried to implement handler for POST with return HttpResponse but nothing change. I don't understand cause it's look like my view is not call.

Comment: Look at the web server error log - you might discover there why the 500 internal server error is occurring. Perhaps the request is failing _before_ being dispatched to your view.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like instagram uses `POST` method to access to your callback url.

Try this:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def getInstagramPicture(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        mode         = request.GET.get("hub.mode")
        challenge    = request.GET.get("hub.challenge")
        verify_token = request.GET.get("hub.verify_token")
        return HttpResponse(challenge)
    if request.method == "POST":
        mode         = request.POST.get("hub.mode")
        challenge    = request.POST.get("hub.challenge")
        verify_token = request.POST.get("hub.verify_token")
        return HttpResponse(challenge)
```

Comment: Same result, my view isn't call when I post photo on Instagram.

Comment: Your view **is** caled using `POST` method.