# Respond to Instagram webhook in Django

Tags: python, django, webhooks, instagram-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I set the callback-url for Instagram webhook, and when Instagram Get my callback-url I should respond to the hub.challenge to verify. Instagram GET request to my endpoint URL:

```
GET https://callback_url/webhooks?
  hub.mode=subscribe&
  hub.challenge=1120110039&
  hub.verify_token=meatyhamhock
```

My code in vews.py:

```
def getInstagramWebhook(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        mode         = request.GET.get("hub.mode")
        challenge    = request.GET.get("hub.challenge")
        verify_token = request.GET.get("hub.verify_token")
        return challenge
```

But I have this error:

```
The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value="1120110039", received="\u003C!DOCTYPE html>\n\u003Chtm..."
```

I tried JsonResponse, HttpResponse, and redirect but not work

Comment: What error do you have when you try with `return HttpResponse(challenge)` ?

Comment: @Tiket_dev I got this error: The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value="1120110039", received="\u003C!DOCTYPE html>\n\u003Chtm..."

Comment: I added `content_type='text/plain'` in the `Response` and solved it:
`return HttpResponse(challenge, content_type='text/plain')` @Tiket_dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem :)

I added `content_type='text/plain'` in the Response:

```
return HttpResponse(challenge, content_type='text/plain')
```

And Facebook verified my `callback URL`