# Im building a crud in Django why is my Update function not working?

Tags: python, django, post, crud, put

Im working on a CRUD in python Django, for CR D no problem, but for Updating it is a mess ! :)

For now I have this first error :

```
RuntimeError at /updateUser/36
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data.
```

I dont understand because I have this in my urls.py :

```
    url(r'^removeUser/(\d+)/$', app.views.removeUser, name='removeUser'),
    url(r'^updateUser/(\d+)/$', app.views.updateUser, name='updateUser'),
```

And for removing user there is no problem !

So okay lets add manually this slash at the end of my url and now I get this error :

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: app_employee.name
```

I really don't see what this means

my views.py

```
def addUser(request):
    """Add new employee"""

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreationUserForm(request.POST)

        newEmployee = Employee()
        newEmployee.name = form['employeeName'].value()
        newEmployee.email = form['employeeEmail'].value()

        newEmployee.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:home'))

def removeUser(request, id_user):
    """Fire an employee"""

    employeeFired = Employee.objects.get(id=id_user)
    employeeFired.delete()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:home'))

def updateUser(request, id_user):
    """Make a change on an employee"""

    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id_user)
    form = UpdateUserForm(request.POST)

    employee.name = form['changeEmployeeName'].value()
    employee.email = form['changeEmployeeEmail'].value()

    employee.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:home'))
```

I built update as addUser which works so I dont get the point

Thanks for helping !! :)

Comment: Show your template/frontend code. The error is clear. You are making a POST request to the url `/updateUser/36` and you need to do that request to `/updateUser/36/`

Comment: however In my urls I define '^updateUser/(\d+)/$' exactly as '^removeUser/(\d+)/$' which works
But even if I add this / at the end manually I have a second error

Comment: The problem is not in tour `urls.py` the problem seems to be the way you are calling this url. For example if you are doing this with jQuery you may have some code that does something linke `$.post('/updateUser/' + user.id, /* more stuff here */)` and you should do `$.post('/updateUser/' + user.id + '/', /* more stuff here */)`

Comment: Refer to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/djangolearning/comments/4o21lm/cant_figure_out_whats_causing_runtimeerror_at/) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738824/django-post-url-error)

Comment: Thank you finally the problem was just removing a / at the end of url(r'^updateUser/(\d+)/$ => url(r'^updateUser/(\d+)$  Really really strange problem because the url for removeUser worked without problem

Answer (score 0):

see
if I change the views.py by:

```
def updateUser(request, id_user):
    """Make a change on an employee"""

    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id_user)
 #   form = UpdateUserForm(request.POST)

    employee.name = "static name"
    employee.email = "static email"

    employee.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:home'))
```

it works I get "static name" and "static email"

so the problem is for sure in views.py